# My dog doesn't eat food himself

Tags: dogs

I put the food in this bowl, but my dog doesn't eat his food himself until I feed him with my own hands. (I have only 1 dog).

Don't know why?

I have tried the following:

1. Change the bowl
2. Change the level *(height)* of the bowl
3. Change the eating place

Comment: This question is different because in the other question, he is having 3 dogs and I have only one.

Comment: The answer applies for 1 dog or 3, it includes suggestions which you have not tried.

Comment: I have tried that too.

Comment: Then update your question to include what the vet said, after the visit when, your dog had not eaten anything for two days.